# Error al intentar leer un campo android.accounts.Account.name

Tags: android, autenticación, oauth2, google+

Marca nullpointerexception cuando intenta leer una cadena sobre un objeto nulo, el campo es `android.accounts.Account.name`, el cual no lo implemento, pero tal vez el Google API para conectarse a traves de Google+ pueda estar realizando al obtener el nombre del Usuario

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'java.lang.String android.accounts.Account.name' on a null object
>   reference     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1690)    at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)     at
>   com.android.vending.contentfilters.IContentFiltersService$Stub$Proxy.getContentFiltersAndIntent(SourceFile:139)
>     at
>   com.google.android.videos.service.contentfiltering.ContentFiltersManager$1$2.get(SourceFile:483)
>     at
>   com.google.android.videos.service.contentfiltering.ContentFiltersManager$1$2.get(SourceFile:477)
>     at
>   com.google.android.videos.utils.async.SupplyToReceiverRunnable.run(SourceFile:29)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>     at
>   com.google.android.videos.utils.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(SourceFile:42)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: esta no es una pregunta! estas solo afirmando que se cae porque es nulo... si quieres ayuda postea tu código